# How many people at the party?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> At a party, there are $n$ people. A waiter counts 188 cin-cin. How
>   many people partecipate at the toast?

I have solved the problem in this way:

$\displaystyle\frac{n(n-1)}{2}=188$ but I haven't obtained an integer number...

Maybe I'd have to consider that more than 2 persons could be involved in a single cin-cin... Could you help me?

Comment: The waiter misses 2 cin-cin.

Comment: If you consider more than $2$ persons at the cin-cin this would make the problem really complicated I think.

Comment: @JimmyR. Maybe it's overkill. Is there a solution for 2-person cin-cin?

Comment: If at each cin-cin there are two persons then your solution is correct $188=\dbinom{n}{2}$. So, if 188 was correct, $n$ should be an integer. Or do you mean something else ?

Comment: @JimmyR. the problem is: that $n$ isn't an integer. What can I say about the number of people at the party?

Comment: If it was 190 instead of 188 then $n=20$ would be the answer. Now with 188 you get n=19.89. So, perhaps you should answer that there at least 20 people at the party and that the waiter has missed at least 2 cin-cins.